# Problem with modulus inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am not able to see if this inequality is right or wrong.

Help anyone

"If $|u|\leq1$ and $|v|\leq1$, then $|u-v|\leq2$"

I tried to see a connection using the inequality identities like

$$|u+v|\leq|u|+|v|$$
 $$|u-v|\leq||u|-|v||$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|u-v| \leq |u|+|-v|=|u|+|v| \leq 2$$